# Character class progression in Fire Emblem Awakening

Tags: fire-emblem-awakening

I just powered through Awakening on Normal/Classic and noticed something at the end, and would like to know if it was just a coincidence, or something I should use for strengthening my team when doing Hard/Classic. I re-classed Panne from a Taguel (level 30) to a trickster (who I leveled to 20) and she went from one of the weaker support players on my team, to easily one of my top 3. I did the same thing with my avatar, who I leveled from tactician (level 20) -> grandmaster (level 20) -> re-class to Dark Mage (level 20) -> Sorcerer (level 20) which again made my avatar a lot stronger than before. My question is, did I happen to get lucky and find classes that were much more suited for these characters, or does re-classing actually make characters stronger? If so, can I re-class them multiple times for even better results? (something like with Chrom: lord -> greatlord, and repeat that process a few times using a secondary seal).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Awakening, characters have no level cap, and switching a character's class brings them down to the first level of that class without lowering their stats.  This means that your level 20 Trickster Panne has all the stat gains of 30 levels of Taguel and 20 levels of Trickster.  Even with the Random Number God screwing you, that's a lot of growth she's had.  Your Robin or Avatar or DTS or whatever you've named him/her is essentially level 80!

Yes, you can do this with whomever you want, however you want (give Tharja 20 levels in General!  Why not?), as much as you want and have the patience to do.  There is one issue: each character and class combination has stat caps, meaning there's a point where a stat won't grow anymore.  If Chrom's Strength as a Great Lord is above 30 or so and you turn him back into a Lord, his Strength will go down to his cap (31 or something like that) and not get any higher until you reclass him back into Great Lord.